# Is it possible to optimize this recursive function?

Tags: c, tree

I am trying to understand if this is the fastest way possible to delete a node in the Tree.

```c
struct node *deleteNode(struct node *root, char *key)
{
    // base case
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    // If the key to be deleted
    // is smaller than the root's
    // key, then it lies in left subtree
    if (strcmp(key, root->key) < 0)
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key);

    // If the key to be deleted
    // is greater than the root's
    // key, then it lies in right subtree
    else if (strcmp(key, root->key) > 0)
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key);

    // if key is same as root's key,
    // then This is the node
    // to be deleted
    else
    {
        // node with only one child or no child
        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }

        // node with two children:
        // Get the inorder successor
        // (smallest in the right subtree)
        struct node *temp = minValueNode(root->right);

        // Copy the inorder
        // successor's content to this node
        root->key = temp->key;

        // Delete the inorder successor
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->key);
    }
    return root;
}
```

It takes a tree and a word and deletes the node from the tree.
The thing I want to understand is when do I reach a "perfect" optimization level? I have worked a lot on this code and I think it is the best way possible. What can I look for more?

Comment: At first sight it looks OK to me. OTOH this question should rather be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Faster? Don't perform strcmp() twice (possibly) at the top. Hopefully the results of both calls (if second one needed) will be exactly the same.

Comment: recursion can be expensive if your list is huge

Comment: It's a bit more work, but if the tree has lots of nodes, maintaining 'balance' is a small price to pay to prevent degrading to little more than a linked list.

Comment: `if( key[0] < root->key[0] || strcmp( key, root->key ) < 0 )` might save off a few nS by precluding necessity of a function call... Modern compilers may make this "tip" out of date (like me...)

Comment: Sure it is possible to optimize it. The call to `deleteNode` after the call to `minValueNode` duplicates work. It would be better to rotate the in-order successor node to the position of the node being deleted using pointer manipulation instead of pointer copying. That requires keeping track of the parent of the node being deleted, or better yet, keeping track of the link to the node being deleted. That could be done by adding an extra parameter to the recursive function. (The recursive function with the extra parameter could be factored out as a separate function called by `deleteNode`.)

Comment: Imagine if... `minValueNode(...` could return the **parent** of the 'doomed' node (so that it would not have to be found -- again -- to attend its execution...

Comment: One obvious speed improvement would be to call `strcmp` at most *once* for any given tree node.  That's where it's probably spending most of its time.  Why in the world would you call it, see if the result is negative, discard the result, then call it again to see it the discarded result was positive?  You *had it*.  You threw it away.  If you were doing it by hand, would you compare the strings twice if the first compare was non-negative?  Of course not.  So why is your code doing so?  Exercise some common sense.  Call it *once*, and *save the result*.

Comment: As @0___________ said, "recursion is expensive"... A few insertions, a few deletions and the "tree" is a sad, twisted 'stick', but many levels deeper than 'optimal'. More "unary search tree" than "binary..." (aka "linked list") Every subsequent search/insert/delete will pay for that... A good start for a low volume tree... Time to attack a "balanced binary tree" implementation... Tricky, but wonderful feeling of achievement when it works! Good luck...

Comment: When using recursivity,  the stack space must be optimized. So, define temp once at the top level of the "else" branch instead of defining one temp per branch.

Comment: A tree structure which doesn't utilize recursion but loops is much faster. However, you'll then have to solve the stacking in some other way, like providing a separate array of pointers to nodes acting as "stack" through a counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the initial parameter to deleteNode is the root, but you should actually name it just `node` or `subtree`.

You should `free` the key, and `strdup` the key on node creation.

Finding the value at that node you cannot immediately delete that node.
Either look at the left's max value (left - rights - rightnull node) or rights min value (right - lefts - leftnull node).

You have three pointers, root, xnull node, and the xnull node's other subtree.
One form of deleting is called *rotating the pointers*.

Notice you do copy the key. In C++ that could be more costly that a pointer copy. In C copying a pointer or at most a struct is similarly costly, though I would favor a pointer copy.

Then you descend the branch again, so there can be optimized a bit; at least more immediate.

```
struct node *deleteNode(struct node *tree, char *key)
{
    // base case
    if (tree == NULL)
        return tree;

    // If the key to be deleted
    // is smaller than the tree's
    // key, then it lies in left subtree
    int cmp = strcmp(key, tree->key); // Thanks to RachidK
    if (cmp < 0)
        tree->left = deleteNode(tree->left, key);

    // If the key to be deleted
    // is greater than the tree's
    // key, then it lies in right subtree
    else if (cmp > 0)
        tree->right = deleteNode(tree->right, key);

    // if key is same as tree's key,
    // then This is the node
    // to be deleted
    else
    {
        struct node *result;
        // node with only one child or no child
        if (tree->left == NULL)
        {
            result = tree->right;
        }
        else if (tree->right == NULL)
        {
            result = tree->left;
        }
        else
        {
            // node with two children:
            // Get the inorder successor
            // (smallest in the right subtree)
            struct node **successor = &(tree->right);
            while ((*successor)->left != NULL)
            {
                successor = &(*successor)->left;
            }
            // rotate pointers:
            result = *successor;
            result->left = tree->left;
            *successor = result->right;
            result->right = tree->right;
        }
        free(tree->key);
        free(tree);
        return result;
    }
    return tree;
}
```

I did not test it. Not `successor` being an alias of first a `right` and then of `left` fields.

Comment: Call strcmp() once  and use its results : int cmp = strcmp(); if (cmp < 0) ... else if (cmp > 0)

Comment: @RachidK. that, in fact is the most obvious and a strong optimization. I'll add it.

Comment: @JoopEggen did you do some performance tests to proof that is **more efficient**?

Comment: @0___________ There is no difference in time complexity and the recursive `minValueNode` could be written as my while loop. The OP's code walks the left path twice, which is my major point. As the data type of `key` is a `char*` copying `key` does not cost extra, instead of my copying of node pointers. But hey, a question on "optimization" often is asking for some feedback, an other approach. More interesting I would look for keeping the tree as balanced as possible: keeping paths to the leaf nodes short. Like whether to swap with successor or predecessor. What do you think?